# Core Data custom metadata not saving for iCloud store

Tags: ios, core-data, metadata, icloud

I am trying to save some custom metadata to an iCloud-enabled Core Data SQLite store. The documentation appears to say that in addition to the metadata it generates, I should be able to set my own custom metadata - similar to NSUserPreferences, but attached to my Core Data store. It seems like it should be simple:

```
NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];

NSMutableDictionary* metadata = [[psc metadataForPersistentStore:store] mutableCopy];
metadata[@"testKey"] = @"testValue";
[psc setMetadata:metadata forPersistentStore:store];
[moc save:&error];
```

So after this runs my custom metadata key/value is visible in the store's metadata field. However, when I restart the app the metadata I added is no longer there (but the iCloud metadata is there). Note that this works correctly when using a regular non-iCloud store so it appears to be iCloud specific.

**Additional information:**

So lets say I get the metadata, add my custom fields and then save it using the static methods:

```
[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator setMetadata:metadata forPersistentStoreOfType:NSSQLiteStoreType URL:self.coreDataController.iCloudStore.URL error:&error];
NSDictionary* reviewMetadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:NSSQLiteStoreType URL:self.coreDataController.iCloudStore.URL error:&error];
```

The `reviewMetadata` variable contains the metadata with my added fields. However once I restart the app (and consequently reload the store) it's back to the way it was. I even tried setting a breakpoint and killing the app right after executing the above statements and when I restart the app my custom metadata is still gone.

Any ideas? Am I using metadata incorrectly? Does this not work with iCloud-enabled stores?

Comment: You are saving, but is there something changed in the `moc`? There could be an optimization in place where if `hasChanges` is false, it does nothing.

Comment: Did you verify that both when writing and reading the persistent store co-ordinator belongs to the correct managed object context?

Comment: I added some more code to show that I am using the correct moc. I have also tried it on the main thread moc and it still didn't work. I also tried it with the static setMetadata:forPersistentStoreOfType:URL:error: method on NSPersistentStore. Still no luck :(

Comment: @kurtzmarc Did you ever solve this problem? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @hpique My latest theory is that this issue was just due to a bad iCloud store. If you wipe your iCloud store and start fresh you may get it working. I have to revisit this and make sure that's the case.

Comment: @kurtzmarc Thanks for replying. I resorted to add the metadata inside a Config entity inside the store. At least there I have more control about what's going on.

Comment: @hpique Don't forget though - you may have issues when it comes to syncing that Config entity. Let's say you want to run an operation *once* per store and you check the Config entity at startup. The user brings up two devices at the same time, and then the operation runs on each device and then the whole mess gets synced together. That may not be what you want.

Comment: @kurtzmarc Wouldn't you have the same problem with store metadata?

Comment: Yeah, nevermind about that. That problem still exists with metadata.

Comment: @LeoNatan It seems that updated metadata does not count as `hasChanges`, so if you would only save on `hasChanges` you will not in fact save. But `[moc save:]` will still save the changed metadata - apparently there is no internal check on `hasChanges` before saving.

Comment: @mvds Thanks. Looks like bad API design, set metadata in coordinator, save from context. Time for a radar.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me but this is running on OS X.  Have not tried the same on iOS.

```
- (void)setiCloudMetaDataForStore:(NSURL*)fileURL ofType:(NSString *)fileType iCloud:(bool)iCloudEnabled ubiquityName:(NSString*)ubiquityName {
    //LOG(@"setiCloudMetaDataForStore called...");

    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *metaData = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:fileType URL:fileURL error:&error];

    if (!metaData) {
        FLOG(@" problem getting metaData");
        FLOG(@"  - error is %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }

    //FLOG(@" metaData is %@", metaData);

    //Now see if we can add a setting to indicate it is iCloud enabled
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:metaData];

    [dict setObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:iCloudEnabled] forKey:@"iCloudEnabled"];

    if (!iCloudEnabled)
        [dict removeObjectForKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];
    else
        [dict setObject:ubiquityName forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];

    bool result = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator setMetadata:dict forPersistentStoreOfType:fileType URL:fileURL error:&error];

    if (!result) {
        FLOG(@" problem setting metaData");
        FLOG(@"  - error is %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that changes to metadata are (sometimes) kept in the -wal and -shm files, that apparently serve to speed up sqlite. I did not find another way to get my metadata changes in the .sqlite file than to add this option while opening the sqlite store:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{NSSQLitePragmasOption:@{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"}};
```

Using this option the -wal and -shm file are not created, so everything must be committed to the .sqlite file.